# sass реализация ::before

Tags: css, sass

пытаюсь прописать красную полоску как на картинке, но пока ничего не выходит

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мой код

```
.news h2
 color: $red

 &::before
  margin-top: 15px
  margin-bottom: -18px
  content: ""
  height: 1px
  width: 50%
  position: relative
  background: green
  display: inline-block
```

может кто-нибудь помочь?

Answer (score 1):

Например можно так реализовать:

```
.news h2
  color: red
  padding-left: 50px
  position: relative
  &:before
    margin-top: 15px
    content: ""
    height: 1px
    width: 50px
    left: 0
    position: absolute
    background: green
    display: inline-block
```

[Посмотреть на CodePen](https://codepen.io/semenchenko/pen/QqWdzo)